# how do I put solfege on for chords?

Tags: chords, chord-theory, sheet-music, solfege

[image]

How do I put on solfege for multiple notes stacked/chords? I mean, I could put it separately, but how do I indicate which solfege goes to which note?

Comment: Are you asking how to sing two notes at once? Or are you simply writing in the solfège and want to know a system for clarifying which syllable goes with which pitch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard way to annotate chords is to stack the annotations in the same order as the chord pitches.

```
X: 1
T: Solfege for chords
M: none
K: none
L: 3/8
[FB]
w:ti
w:fa
```

Comment: is there a standard way? I know sheet music where they write the solfege names above the soprano and alt (treble clef)  and below the tenor and bass (bass clef).

Answer (score 0):

If you are a beginner and have not practice in sight reading and using movable doremi I recommend what I practiced with my students:

Use bigger staves than we have in ordinary printed music or blow your sheet music up that you are able to write the names exactly in the place of the note heads and not above or below the lines:
e.g. fa,la,do,mi in the spaces of  the treble clef (in C major) and mi,so,ti,re,fa right in the line (like the note heads). The same technique is useful for beginners when learning the absolute note names (c,d,e,f,g ...)